# linearly independent in Hilbert Space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Please help me to solve the linearly independent of functions in Hilbert Space

how i can show that the functions $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ are linearly independent in Hilbert Space (L^2[0,pi])?

Comment: By showing that $\cos$ is not a scalar multiple of $\sin$.

Comment: Which Hilbert space are we talking about? For example in $\Bbb{R}^1$ they are not (irrespective of the value of $t$). In $L^2([0,2\pi])$ they are, because they are orthogonal and non-zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: You're in a Hilbert space, so you have the scalar product $\langle\cdot\vert\cdot\rangle$. Nonzero orthogonal vectors are always linearly independent. Can you check that $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(t)\overline{\cos(t)}\,dt=0$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$ such that 
$$\alpha \cos(t)+\beta\sin(t)=0\;\forall t\in\mathbb R$$
now choose a particular value of $t$ to show that $\alpha=\beta=0$ and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be the Wronskian.

**added**

The Wronskian for a linearly dependent list of functions is identically zero.  Compute the Wronskian for $\sin x, \cos x$,
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}\sin x & \cos x\\ \cos x & -\sin x\end{matrix}\right| = -\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x = -1
$$
to see that it is not identically zero.

Comment: Dear GEdgar: I'm positive this is the kernel of a great hint, but as written it's pretty vague and doesn't really rise beyond the content of a comment. If you find the time, could you beef it up with another sentence alluding to the relevant property? Thanks!